# Convert object into array of object values

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, react-hooks

In React I have a state:

```
const [selecteditems, setSelectedItems] = useState()
```

On form submit I have an object that looks like this `{items: {item1: true, item2: true, item3: false}}`
I need to turn this object into an array of objects that looks like this: `[{ name: 'item1', price: ''}, {name: 'item2', price: ''}]` to use with `setSelectedItems`

Then I would like to be able to update prices of individual items using `setSelectedItems`. How would I achieve this?

To recap, first I need to convert an object into an array of objects, then I need to update individual price values in the array of objects separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `filter` and `map`. For updating an object, `find` can be used.

```js
const obj = {items: {item1: true, item2: true, item3: false}};
const res = Object.entries(obj.items).filter(([k,v]) => v)
    .map(([k]) => ({name: k, price: ''}));
console.log(res);
//update
let name = 'item2';
res.find(x => x.name === name).price = '$10';
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    const items = {items: {item1: true, item2: true, item3: false}}
    const itemArray = [];
    Object.keys(items.items).forEach((key) => {
      if (items.items[key])
        itemArray.push({
          name: key,
          price: '',
        });
    });

    setSelectedItems(itemArrary);
```

---

Update price

```
    const name = 'item1';

    const _itemArray = [...itemArray];
    const index = _itemArray.findIndex(item => item.name === name);

    if (index !== -1) {
        _itemArray[index].price = '$100';
        setSelectedItems(_itemArray);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use `reduce()` also.

```js
const value = {items: {item1: true, item2: true, item3: false}} 
// [{ name: 'item1', price: ''}, {name: 'item2', price''}]


const res = Object.entries(value.items).reduce((acc, [k,v]) => {
  return v ? acc.concat({ name: k, price: '' }) : acc;
},[])

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can to this

```js
const price = [{ name: 'item1', price: ''}, {name: 'item2', price: ''}]

const newPrice = {
name: "item1",
price: "$1000"
}

const results = price.map((x) => x.name === "item1" ? newPrice : x)
console.log(results)
```